# SSAS mdx query ParallelPeriod

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to create a calculated measure in SSAS using an MDX query. This measure should return the average amount within a period of a year and the same period last year. I've found out about the ParallelPeriod function but couldn't manage to use it.

My query should look like this

```
(
 AGGREGATE(
   {[TF_Product].[LastDayOfMonth]}
   *{[TF_Product].[Category].&[Deposits]},
   [Measures].[Montant]
 )
 +
 AGGREGATE(
   { Get the date of the same period last year using parallelperiod}
   *{[TF_Product].[Category].&[Deposits]},
   [Measures].[Montant]
 )
)/2
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you.

Comment: The Daily average? So `(1jan-4Apr2015 + 1jan-4Apr2016)/numdays` ?

Comment: I want to calculate for example : (amount in January 2016 + amount in January 2015) / 2

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
...
MEMBER [Measures].[Avg of 2 Mths] AS
  Avg(
    {[Date].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(12),[Date].[Month].CurrentMember}
    [Measures].[Sales Quantity]
  )
...
```

It works in this context:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Avg of 2 Mths] AS 
    Avg
    (
      {
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(12)
       ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
      }
,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]  
  ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Avg of 2 Mths]} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is the result:

[image]

(755527.89 + 577314)/ 2 = 666420.95

Comment: @yasmine92 not the most helpful comment !

Comment: Sorry ! :( I'll try again

Comment: @yasmine92 no worries - I was just complaining because it is very likely it might not work but just saying "It's not working ! " doesn't really help me come up with something else for you ...if you detail the way in which it isn't working then we can go from there - is it returning the wrong numbers? or is it actually throwing an exception with an error message?

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of the table I don't have a time hierarchy I want to use YEAR and MONTH members. How can I do that ?

Comment: It's returning null value

Answer (score 0):

This works?

```
with member [Measures].AvgAmnt as
(
 AGGREGATE(
   {[TF_Product].[Calendar].Currentmember}
   *{[TF_Product].[Category].Currentmember},
   [Measures].[Montant]
 )
 +
 AGGREGATE(
   {ParallelPeriod([TF_Product].[Calendar].[Month],1,[TF_Product].[Calendar].Currentmember)}
   *{[TF_Product].[Category].Currentmember},
   [Measures].[Montant]
 )
)/2

select [TF_Product].[Calendar].[Date].members * [TF_Product].[Category].members on 1,
[Measures].AvgAmnt on 0
from [SomeCube]
```

Have assumed you have a Date hierarchy(Calendar) in place in your cube.

Comment: No I don't have a time hierarchy in my cube. I've been trying to use your code but it's not working. Isn't there any way to do it without a hierarchy ?

Comment: Concept of `ParallelPeriod` is unusable without a time hierarchy in place. Do you have contiguous dates in the cube? Or does it have dates pertaining to transactions(in which case there could be "gaps")?

Comment: The dates aren't contiguous I have the last day of month the month and the year